# C - Read file and count rows and columns

Tags: c++, c, file, count

- I am trying to make a function to read a file
- It should count the **rows** and **columns**
- Set the global variables to be the new rows and columns that were read in

My issue is that I can read the rows, but i can't seem to be able to read the columns right.

**File:** http://collabedit.com/qjytg

Would anyone be able to help>

```
matrix: 
#########
#       #
#       #
#       #
#       #
#########


#include <stdio.h>

void read_file(const char *file_name);

size_t rows = 10; 
size_t cols = 20; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //function call

}

void read_file(const char *file_name) {
    FILE *myfile = fopen(file_name, "r");
    int newRows = 0; 
    int newCols = 0; 
    char ch;

    while(!feof(myfile)) {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        if(ch == '\n') {
            newRows++; 
        } else {
            newCols++;
        }
    }
    rows = newRows; 
    cols = newCols; 
}
```

Comment: can you specify the format of the file that you would like to read in? What are columns separated with?

Comment: They are exactly the way the matrix is shown above. --> I will attach a file

Comment: Please read some books (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I think, answering this question is no good.

Comment: You don't set columns back to 0 when you start reading a new line.

Comment: So the number of columns is just the number of #s in the first row?

Comment: @gen - yes the number of # in a row

Comment: I recommend you read some existing [examples on stack overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+matrix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  The results were found by searching the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file matrix".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Here's the small trick or a problem you had to dodge, When you find a new row. You had to make the column count to 0. Which may be you've missed. Replace the `if` block to the one below and it should work fine

```
if(ch == '\n') 
{
    newRows++; 
    cols=newCols;
    newCols=0;
}
```

the `fgetc` line also has a filename error

```
ch = fgetc(myfile);
```

Comment: @DieterLücking where have I specifed it being wrong?

Comment: you have not, but missed it

Comment: Although, I thought let me not fill the answers with suggestions. I just specified bare minimum things which would make the program work. Thanks anyway @DieterLücking